# PHP Websocket echo server crashes

Tags: php, websocket

We are using a websocket algorithm on a dedicated server running with apache and php5, everything works correctly except sometimes we got errors making the echo server crash. There are the 3 errors happened in the algorithm (comments in this part of code) :

```
                    $numBytes = @socket_recv($socket,$buffer,$this->maxBufferSize,0);


                    if ($numBytes === false)
                    {
                        /* 110 :  Connection timed out */
                        /* 113 : No route to host */
                        /* 104 : Connection reset by peer */
                        $error_msg = socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
                        socket_close($this->master);
                        throw new Exception('Socket error: ' . $error_msg);
                    }
```

This code part is within an infinite while. I dont paste everything and nothing to keep the post clean but feel free to ask me more code. Does anyone know why these errors happens, and is there a way to make them non-crashing the entire script ?

Here's the way that the server starting :

```
        $this->maxBufferSize = 2048;
        $this->master = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)  or die("Failed: socket_create()");
        socket_set_option($this->master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) or die("Failed: socket_option() (reuse address)");
        socket_set_option($this->master,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>1, "usec"=>100)) or die("Failed: socket_option() (timeout)");
        socket_bind($this->master, $addr, $port)                      or die("Failed: socket_bind()");
        socket_listen($this->master)                               or die("Failed: socket_listen()");
        $this->sockets['m'] = $this->master;
```

Comment: "This code part is within an infinite while" scares me. That statement alone makes me guess that this is your issue. Does the `while(){}` ever get a `break;` under some condition?

Comment: absolutely not, it seems to be the unique and correct way, like you can see here : https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/%20phpwebsocket/server.php (line 13 to 32)

Comment: I think PHP is not meant for constant lisening like this. Node.js or Python Tornado would be better for web socked servers.
But if You are stuck with PHP - I would place my bet on some kind of timeout of php script runing time - either on PHP or apache site.
Did You check that when error occurrs the server script is still running?